# Throwing argument exceptions in method overloads

Tags: c#, exception

I just recently started looking into exceptions and best practices for their use and I wonder what is the correct way of doing this:

Suppose there is a method with multiple arguments. And there are multiple overloads for this method with less parameters, which call the main implementation by providing default values.

**Do I validate all arguments in every overload?**

```
public string Translate(string text)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    return Translate(text, "english");
}

public string Translate(string text, string language)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    // Do the rest of the work
    // ...
}
```

**Do I rethrow the exceptions?**

```
public string Translate(string text)
{
    try
    {
        return Translate(text, "english");
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public string Translate(string text, string language)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    // Do the rest of the work
    // ...
}
```

**Or do I completely drop exceptions and try/catch blocks in the overload?**

```
public string Translate(string text)
{
    return Translate(text, "english");
}

public string Translate(string text, string language)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    // Do the rest of the work
    // ...
}
```

---

**Also, how would the documentation of the two methods look like?**

(Using C# XML comments. Especially where I put the `<exception>` elements.)

---

I do realize that this is a minor topic, still, I keep wondering everytime I encounter this kind of situation (which is actually quite often).

Comment: Optional arguments solves this in a way, only one method:
public string Translate(string text, string language="english")

Comment: Oh, wow, I have been programming with C# for more than a year and I  really had no idea that this is possible.

Comment: I wrote it as an answer then, am kinda tired at the moment and did not really know if it was an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) solves this in a way, then you have only one method:

```
public string Translate(string text, string language="english")
```

There are some [quirks with optional arguments](http://www.grumpydev.com/2010/04/19/optional-parameters-in-c4-c3-and-vb-net-with-a-side-order-of-il-quirks/) that are good to know about.

> the default values are “baked into” the calling code. [...]
>   The issue this can cause is the same for exposing public consts – if
>   you change the default values in a library, but don’t recompile the
>   calling code, then the calling code will still call your method(s)
>   with the old default values. This is definitely something you need to
>   consider when designing APIs using optional parameters.

Comment: This definitely solves the problem in the above example. Still, is it possible to think of a situation, where you cannot use an optional argument? For example, if some additional work requires you to have an additional method. Then the question would still be relevant.

Comment: Yes, that is why I wrote it as a comment first, did not know if you wanted a solution for your specific case or the general case.

Answer (score 2):

Lets make a pros and cons list of the three options you have got and decide :

**1. Do I validate all arguments in every overload?**

Pros : You get to know whether the string is empty and then throw the exception. Classic and good.
Cons : You are calling the second function after the exception is thrown, knowing that exception occured due to string empty or null.

So I would drop this idea.

**2. Do I rethrow the exceptions?**

Pros : 1) This is my personal favorite as if you go line by line this is what happens. The second function is called and there the exception is thrown and caught in the calling function's catch and some other jobs are done. 
       2) using throw keyword instead of throw ex make sure that your stack trace is intact.
       3) Handling an exception at the calling part is the best practice.

Cons : Please help me with the cons. I dont find any.

**3. Or do I completely drop exceptions and try/catch blocks in the overload?**

Pros : Try catch is not used in the calling function. Not exactly a pros, but ehh, it reduces some code. 
Cons : Proper handling is not there and the best practice says we should handle the exception at the calling function.

I think the second option is the best option.

Also there is a link I would like to share which is really helpful

[Best Practice : Code Project Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET)

Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't really understand the cons from (1), though. And as for (3): if I don't want to do anything with the exception and just rethrow it, using a try/catch seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this a traditional issue in what has been recognized in crypto as best done with what is called static factory methods - usually named `getInstance()` - in which you refactor a lot of the question into one place.
It gets rather nasty trying to wade through all the responses you get but never throw away exceptions by doing nothing at all, just simplify greatly for end-use-case and either keep something in a log and fail-fast or make sure you are in a student setting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to answering here, but I wanted to point out that if you're doing overloads properly, this really shouldn't be an issue. The correct way to overload to is to put all the functional code in a method that accepts all possible params:

```
public string Foo(string param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    // do work here, including throwing argument exceptions
}
```

Then, your overloads should fill missing params with default values:

```
public string Foo(string param1)
{
    return Foo(param1, null, null);
}

public string Foo(string param1, string param2)
{
    return Foo(param1, param2, null);
}
```

Based on that, then, you need only handle your exceptions in your primary overload (the one that actually does stuff). Just bear in mind that your overloads should not themselves cause an exception to be raised. For example, if `param3` was enforced to be not null via throwing `ArgumentNullException`, then you shouldn't pass `null` for that param, but rather some actual string that can serve as a default.

No matter which overload ends up being called, the primary overload (with the throws) is called, and any exceptions it throws will bubble up to the originating code. In other words, you don't need to do something like:

```
public string Foo(string param1)
{
    if (param1 == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param1));
    }

    return Foo(param1, "param2 default", "param3 default");
}
```

Because the primary overload already has that check and will throw if `param1` is null.